# Table View Design Issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uitextfield, storyboard

My app design required a page that display 'user information' and i currently have this setup using a simple table view in a View controller. Now, the tricky thing is I need to be able to provide functionality to the user to be able to edit these on the same same screen. So essentially when the user taps on a row in the table view, I want that little flashing text line at the end of the current text in the row so the user can edit what's currently present and I also want a save button to apear on the top when  a user has started editing. The tricky part is, not all fields in my table view will be editable. So, I need certain fields to be editable and have the save button appear and certain fields not. 
Can you tell me how would I go about modifying my existing design to implement this functionality? I would appreciate some code if you think you can show me how exactly I would go about doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably want to make some custom UITableViewCells.  You can fill a tableview with all sorts of different cells which are different sizes and looks different, all at the same time.  I would suggest a custom UITableViewCell which will hold a UITextField as one of the subviews.  On the cells which you don't want user interaction with the textfield, either make a new custom cell that uses a UILabel or just do textfield.userInteractionEnabled = NO.  Look up some custom uitableviewCell tutorials to get you started and then use the approach that I suggested for your problem.